# MoveNext not working with part of -or

Tags: powershell

I have a simple bit of code as follows:

```
foreach ($someFile in Get-ChildItem) {
    if (($someFile.Name.Substring(0,1) -eq "R") -or ($someFile.Name.Substring(0,1) -eq "S") {
        $foreach.MoveNext() | Out-Null
        $someFile.Name
    }
}
```

The idea of this simple example was to output all file names **except** for those that begin with the letter "R" or "S".

When I run this in a directory with one file that begins with "R" and one that begins with "S" along with some other files it skips over the "S" file as intended, but the "R" file name still gets displayed.

I know that there are other ways that I can accomplish this, but this was an attempt to make sure that I was using the `foreach` correctly before using it in a more complicated bit of code.

Can anyone see something wrong with the code above? It seems like it should work to me. I've also confirmed that `$someFile.Name.Substring(0,1) -eq "R"` returns `True` for the "R" file as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are returning `$someFile.Name`, so that will give `S` file when `R` occurs and in the next iteration, it would go to `T` ( or whatever is next ) and not `S`. Logic also breaks down when there are multiple R files etc.

If you just want to skip the `R` and `S` files, probably you want to just use `continue`:

```
foreach ($someFile in Get-ChildItem)
{
    if (($someFile.Name.Substring(0,1) -eq "R") -or ($someFile.Name.Substring(0,1) -eq "S"))
    {
        continue

    }
    $foreach.Current.Name  # $somefile.Name
}
```

Also, you can use `String.StartsWith` rather than the SubString. Or use `-like` and combine it into a single check.

Comment: This does kind of the opposite of what I'm trying to do, but it pointed me in the right direction. Substituting `continue` for `MoveNext()` fixed the issue. Now to look into `MoveNext()` to see why it isn't behaving how I thought it would.

Comment: @TomH. - I gave the explanation in the first para for why it didn't work the way you wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($someFile in Get-ChildItem) {
    if ($someFile.Name -notlike '[RS]*') {
        $someFile.Name
    }
}
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem -Exclude '[RS]*' | %{ $_.Name }
```

Comment: This still results in the same problem, although instead of the "R" filename being listed, the "S" one is.

Comment: What is the task? Output all files but R* and S*? From your code I thought "to output a file NEXT to R* or S*"

Comment: I want to output all files except for R* and S*. I'll make that clearer in my question.

Comment: OP says he knows there are other ways of doing it and wanted to know how to do in foreach. So the second example is not applicable.